# Amazon S3 can not upload file via Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to upload a file to S3 via Cloudfront with signed URL. 
HTTP PUT is allowed in Cloudfront Behavior.
Bucket Policy

> ```
>              {
>         "Sid": "2",
>         "Effect": "Allow",
>         "Principal": {
>             "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E1C2T5UJU07REZ"
>         },
>         "Action": [
>             "s3:PutObject",
>             "s3:PutObjectAcl",
>             "s3:GetObject"
>         ],
>         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testback/*"
>     }
> ```

HTTP PUT  is allowed in CORS configuration.
Cloudfront User also has read, writes permission.
When I am trying upload file with signed URL.

```
curl -v -X PUT -F file=@hello.txt  http://my-host.cloudfront.net/hello.txt?Expires=1514764800&Signature=MySig&Key-Pair-Id=My-KeyPair
```

I've got an error:

> `InvalidRequest`The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.  5D5DEF3D06F4583C8rBCpTUzYwm1ccc8IfkNtUnkuLxr3RZ2n7xn1j+VvP5dpG+3NMpHKPiNQ5tKpJjVliZ9UBI52vk=

Log:

> 2017-06-19      03:23:08        FRA54   726     My-IP  PUT
>   my-host.cloudfront.net   /hello.txt      400     -
>   curl/7.50.1
>   Expires=1514764800&Signature=My-Sig&Key-Pair-Id=My-KeyPair
>   -       Error   MMHwKFzGuBzrlgP0yV71elcwEp2RVBAwJRJD1A5rO4Na6UmeKvcZPQ==
>   my-host.cloudfront.net   http    838     0.235   -  --
>   Error   HTTP/1.1

Also, GET,DELETE works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the CloudFront documentation:

> If you're using an origin access identity and if your bucket is in one of the regions that requires signature version 4 for authentication, note the following:
>
> `DELETE`, `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, and `PATCH` requests are supported without qualifications.
>
> If you want to submit `PUT` requests to CloudFront to upload objects to your Amazon S3 bucket, you must add an `x-amz-content-sha256` header to the request, and the header value must contain a SHA256 hash of the body of the request.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4

You'll need to add the hex representation of the SHA256 of the object body in an `x-amz-content-sha256` request header.

It seems unexpected that CloudFront would use the inclusion of this header in a `PUT` as the magic trigger for internally switching to the V4 signing algorithm... but since it is mandatory for uploads, the V4 signature wouldn't be valid without it, so maybe it doesn't even try V4 (CloudFront pre-dates Signature V4). For other operations, V4 doesn't require modifications to user-agent behavior, but for `PUT`, it would so it would make sense for CloudFront to go with V2 as the default in its absence, even if that's wrong, so that existing code wouldn't break in places where it was already working.  In any event, that seems like this should be your solution.

Comment: @unknown did that solve your issue?  Was [this AWS Forum Post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=258104) yours, also?

Comment: Yes it was help.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot how can I generate `x-amz-content-sha256` for an audio file? I amn using `aws-cloudfront-sign` to generate the signed url in `nodejs`?

Comment: @MaxySpark it's the hex-encoded SHA256 hash of the file's payload, regardless of the type of file.  But note that `x-amz-content-sha256` does not go in the URL -- it's an HTTP request *header*.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot can u plz show me how to get the sha256 encoded hash. i am a beginner. sorry

Comment: Thanks for this great answer... for sake of my application, just wish it were not necessary to add that header

Comment: @openwonk that header is always required -- by S3 -- if the S3 region is a V4 region.  Untested, but if your uploads are under 1MB, you *might* be able to use a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger to do that hash calculation, because Lambda@Edge can now [expose the request body](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-include-body-access.html) to the Lambda trigger function.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot as per docs I don't think you can add x-amz-* headers to origin request https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-origin-custom-headers.html#add-origin-custom-headers-blacklist

Comment: @openwonk i know right... i wish cloudfront would generate this header itself too :(

Comment: @zavr that's a restriction on *custom* origin headers.  If you whitelist the header in question in the cache behavior, you still might be able to add it to the `cf.request.headers` object in a trigger.